# OCP Network Infrastructure

Tags: networking, virtualbox, openshift

I try to set up OCP Cluster with custom network. I set up DHCP and DNS services and all RHCOS nodes take IP address and it's hostname but this cluster have not access to internet. So set up process is interrupted. I aim that all nodes access to internet. And than other way I need custom DHCP server. How should I design network infrastructure (Internal, Nat Network, Host Only Network) on VirtualBox?